# PowerBI Measure going nuts

Tags: powerbi, dax

I'm having a simple Grid in PowerBI Desktop, just to check some data.

It Displays a few Tables Fields and a few Measures with these definitions.

```
_RevenueTranCurr = SUM(Sales[RevenueCurrTrans])
_RevenueTranCurr_LY = SUM(Sales[RevenueCurrTrans_LY])
```

We are not working with Date Logic as the ETL with te Business Logic provides us these fields on 1 line. Nevermind.

Now I would like to have a measure that checks if there is revenue in both years. But even this measures makes the Visual go into error

```
_Sold_IBP_Calc = IF( [_RevenueTranCurr]<>0 ,1,0)

Error : This visual has exceeded the available resources. Try filtering to decrease the amount of data displayed.
```

We are displaying 6 lines of data ... Anybody has an idea what this could be

Comment: Not sure why your model is crashing, but I would definitely use a Calendar table in your model and do the time intelligence measures with it. I would try it, especially since what you're doing isn't working. A Calendar table is pretty small when it comes to dimensions. Then you can use built-in functions if you want like SAMEPERIODLASTYEAR() to shift the evaluation context around. (Or you can write your own... the way Ferrari & Russo do on their DAXPatterns website.

Comment: We get the data in Year-Month periods, could link that to a Calendar, but we need to use the figures that are provides, there is a huge set of business rules that define the LY figures, it's not just a sum off all last-year-data. These business Rules are maintained in another app and executed/calcuated there.